# Slideshow didn't work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, slide

I spent > 8 hours today just to make my slide works but unfortunately it didn't work.It only display the 4 static images.. Why it doesn't work? Can anybody tell me? Here is my code.

```
asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .slides_container {
            width:570px;
            height:270px;
        }
        .slides_container div {
            width:570px;
            height:270px;
            display:block;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slides.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#slides").slides({
                preload: true
            });
        });
    </script>
   .........................
 <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">

<div> <img src= "folder/6.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="folder/7.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="folder/extreme.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="folder/alza.jpg" /></div>
</div>     
</div>
```

Someone who knows my problem, please help me. Appreciate that. Have a nice Tuesday :)

Comment: Looks more like jQuery than asp.net...

Comment: To get a sensible answer, you're probably going to need to define "my page went crazy"

Comment: Please describe "page went crazy".

Comment: edited. Sorry for asking a not-so-clear question.

Comment: Open the page in chrome and look for any script errors (will be a little red/white X in bottom right corner when viewing source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you make use of [**SlideJS**](http://slidesjs.com/)? If I am correct - have a look at this demo code - which worked for me

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .slides_container
    {
        width: 570px;
        height: 270px;
    }
    .slides_container div
    {
        width: 570px;
        height: 270px;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- downloaded from SlideJS and put it in a js folder -->
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slides").slides({
            preload: true
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">
        <div>
            <img src="pic/1.jpg" /></div>
        <div>
            <img src="pic/2.jpg" /></div>
        <div>
            <img src="pic/3.jpg" /></div>
        <div>
            <img src="pic/4.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```